# Problems with Vimeo Player in Android App's WebView

Tags: android, webview, vimeo

In my Android app, I created a WebView to play Vimeo videos.  When I load the activity, the correct preview of the vimeo video appears, but when I attempt to play it, I get the following screen:

[image]

Sometimes the audio from the video plays, but I never get the video.  Here is what I have in my activity:

```
if(mediaURL.toLowerCase().contains("vimeo")){
       Log.d(TAG, "adding viemo");
       final WebView vimeoPlayer = new WebView(MediaPreview.this);
       vimeoPlayer.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
       vimeoPlayer.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       vimeoPlayer.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
       vimeoPlayer.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android Mozilla/5.0 AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
       vimeoPlayer.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
       vimeoPlayer.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
       vimeoPlayer.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
       vimeoPlayer.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
       vimeoPlayer.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
       vimeo_url = mediaURL + "?player_id=player&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&api=1&maxheight=480&maxwidth=800";
       Log.d(TAG, "vimeo_url: " + vimeo_url);
       vimeoPlayer.loadUrl(vimeo_url);
       // vimeoPlayer.loadDataWithBaseURL("", vimeo_url, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                     mediaHolder.addView(vimeoPlayer);;
}
```

I haven't seen any definitive examples of working Vimeo players in Android apps, so if anyone has gotten this to work,  would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: Everything looks pretty good to me not sure why it won't play for you, have you checked this out : https://github.com/droid28/VimeoVideo ?

Comment: thanks!  I was able to get it to work after integrating that example.  couldn't isolate exactly why what I had before didn't work.

Comment: Great ! Glad it worked, you should select my answer and close this question .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Everything looks pretty good to me not sure why it won't play for you, have you checked this out : https://github.com/droid28/VimeoVideo ?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Adnan Mulla for answering, your solutions works has an issue/bug

**Issue:** There is bug in https://github.com/droid28/VimeoVideo It does not stop audio even after finishing the activity.

**Solution:**  One must destroy `WebView` in `onDestroy()`

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mWebView.destroy();
}
```